Communication between Python and FPGA
I am working with the python package pyrpl and trying to set the frequency attribute from the iq module dynamically. Unfortunately, doing so via the python API is too slow for my application. Hence, I need to modify the underlying FPGA code. I checked the hardware implementation of the iq module on github but I am struggling to find the representation of iq.frequency in the Verilog code. Could someone please explain to me how I can track down the mapping of iq.frequency from the python API to the underlying FPGA implementation?
I checked the implementations of the hardware modules found in https://github.com/lneuhaus/pyrpl/tree/main/pyrpl/fpga/rtl.
I was hoping to find the equivalent of iq.frequency from the python API. The goal would be to change the FPGA code in such a way that I can add an additional input to the iq hardware module, which would modify the register for the frequency dynamically.
I am very unfamiliar with Verilog and FPGA coding. Any help would be helpful=)
In https://github.com/lneuhaus/pyrpl/blob/main/pyrpl/hardware_modules/iq.py I found that in the iq class frequency is an instance of a class defined in attributes.py. And it is constructed with the address 0x108. Is this the address of the register where the value of the variable is stored on the FPGA?
